# Show Entry.Number on Cognito Form or print out of form

Tags: cognito-forms

When a user enters data into one of my forms Cognito assigns it an "Entry.Number". But I can't find out how to display the number on the form or printout of the form (e.g. I want to email the user confirmation of their entry with the entry.number shown).

I can see how to add it to the confirmation when the user "submits" but can't add it onto the physical print of the form when I create a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

As you have indicated, you can easily include the entry number on the confirmation page, confirmation emails, etc., by adding the token "Entry.Number" from the Insert Field option when customizing these settings in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

If you want to include the entry number in the generated PDF document, you have two options:

1. You can insert this token into a Content field that is part of your form.
2. You can add a Calculation field that shows the entry number.

Here is an example of how to configure the second option:

[image: Entry Number Conditionally Visible Calculated Field]

This field is also set up to be conditionally visible so it will only appear once the entry has been assigned a number.

Finally, we will be releasing support for custom document merging later this month, which will provide full control over generated Word and PDF documents using your rich form data and calculations.  We are currently beta testing this feature with a few of our customers.

Comment: Jamie ... Many thanks for the prompt reply.  Based on your suggestion I have got it to work :-D